FastAPI Multipart throws 422 Unprocessable Entity
If I remove the UploadFile part, I am able to receive the dictionary and make it work
If I remove the dict and Body(...), I am able to receive the file and make it work
I don't know how with both dict and UploadFile, Code fails with 422 Unprocessable Entity and can't make it to work with multipart
Swagger Test Post below
------WebKitFormBoundaryewMFgxOJYb8xJ70T
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"

{
  "media_title": "string",
  "media_description": "string",
  "media_type": "string",
  "media_tags": "tag1",
  "firm_id": 0,
  "fund_id": 0,
  "user_id": 0,
  "file_path": "string",
  "version": 0
}
------WebKitFormBoundaryewMFgxOJYb8xJ70T
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_file"; filename="file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundaryewMFgxOJYb8xJ70T--

Code:
class Media(BaseModel):
    media_title: str
    media_description: str
    media_type: str
    media_tags: str
    firm_id: int
    fund_id: int = None
    user_id: int
    file_path: str
    version: int

@media_router.post("/upload", response_model=Media)
async def upload_media(db: db_dependency, media: dict = Body(...), media_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        media["file_path"] = save_uploaded_file(media_file)
        output = await dblibrary.create(db=db, obj_in=Media(**media))
        return output
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=str(e))

Error
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "dict_type",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "media"
      ],
      "msg": "Input should be a valid dictionary",
      "input": "{\r\n  \"media_title\": \"string\",\r\n  \"media_description\": \"string\",\r\n  \"media_type\": \"string\",\r\n  \"media_tags\": \"tag1\",\r\n  \"firm_id\": 0,\r\n  \"fund_id\": 0,\r\n  \"user_id\": 0,\r\n  \"file_path\": \"string\",\r\n  \"version\": 0\r\n}",
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/dict_type"
    }
  ]
}


You can not use json Body data and File simultaneously.

You can declare multiple File and Form parameters in a path operation,
but you can't also declare Body fields that you expect to receive as
JSON, as the request will have the body encoded using
multipart/form-data instead of application/json.
This is not a limitation of FastAPI, it's part of the HTTP protocol.

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/?h=upload#define-file-and-form-parameters
Use Form data instead of body. But, Form data doesn't work well with Pydantic models (FastAPI doesn't support it yet), you can use DataClass instead.
UPD: just noticed, that you don't use model for input data. I'm not sure you can do it with Form data.

This question has been answered multiple times in the past.
